# Ensure a component is rendered after DOM update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `ScrollBar` that receives the `CardsContainer` as a ref in order to be able to display some HTML elements under it that allow for some custom scroll behavior.

The issue is, even if the state is updated and the cards are rerendered, the `ScrollBar` will still receive the old node because the node is creating while `ScrollBar` is rendered. How could I get around this?

```
  return (
        <div>
            <CardsContainer ref={nodeRef}>
              {cards.map((card, index) => (
                <Card
                  {...card}
                  index={index}
                  onClickDismiss={handleDismiss}
                />
              ))}
            </CardsContainer>
            <ScrollBar container={nodeRef} />
          </>
        </div>
      )
```

where

```
  const handleDismiss = (index: number) => {
    setCards([...cards.filter((c, i) => i !== index)])
  }
```

P.S. As requested, code of a button click event handler inside `ScrollBar`:

```
  const onClickRightArrow = () => {
    isArrowScroll.current = true
    if (activeIndex < container.children.length - 1) {
      container.children[activeIndex + 1].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'nearest',
        inline: 'center',
      })
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to reconsider using refs for this purpose, is assigning `CardsContainer` and its children to a variable and passing it to `ScrollBar` or rendering it within is not possible?

Comment: @G07cha , `is assigning CardsContainer and its children to a variable and passing it to ScrollBar` - already doing this with `nodeRef`. `rendering it within is not possible` - is possible to render it inside `CardsContainer` tho semantically not recommended, but will I then be able to give `Scrollbar` up to date ref? Inside `ScrollBar` I do things like `container.children[index].scrollIntoView`

Comment: Ah, I see, could you share code that utilizes passed ref in `ScrollBar`?

Comment: @G07cha , I added it in the post

Comment: @G07cha What do you think?

Comment: I think you might have an issue with how you handle ref, I would assume you need to use `container.current` to access ref but you would get an error otherwise. I whipped together a small demo and it seems to work as expected for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-54pe2?file=/index.js